# UIWebView Get Table Element

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have HTML with table that is id is `tableID` :

```
<table id="tableID">
```

and i want get is content, i try to do with with :

```
NSString *helloElement = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementByID('tableID')"];
```

but what u get is an empty string, any idea why?

Comment: I have no idea how these work but I think the element here is "table id" and not "tableID", correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementByID` should not have a capital 'D'. Try `getElementById`

Comment: That will probably be working - just returning you an DOM element, not a string.  If you want the HTML from the table, you can use: document.getElementById('tableID').innerHTML;